# how to grab a screenshot of particular area of webpage in core php on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to grab a screenshot of particular part of webpage on click of button using core php or JS.
i am using imagegrabscreen() to save the screenshot but i dont want to save the whole screen as it contain the taskbar and the title bar of the window.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, it can't take screenshots of a rendered page.

This looks to be similar to what you're after: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: is it possible to save the image generated on the server?
as i read the documentation i am not sure whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I'm sure you could in some way pass the image through an ajax function to a php script that saves the POST to an image.

Comment: is there another way to achieve this